# How do I obtain URL to download the csv files of Tensorflow datasets?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In TensorFlow examples, I can see URLs to download the csv format of the dataset.
For example,

Iris- https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv

Titanic- https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv

However, I can't find the URL for every dataset in TensorFlow that are listed over her. (https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/overview).

Comment: As a workaround you can refer `source code` of respective dataset, for few datasets we need to follow manual instruction as mentioned in document.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need the URLs. Tensorflow datasets are already ready to use. check out the tutorial here [tfds guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview)

For titanic, it is available here [titanic structured dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/titanic)

Hope this would help :)

Answer (score 1):

[TensorFlow Datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets) is having a collection of ready-to-use datasets.
loaded from tfds - "Dataset downloaded and prepared to /root/tensorflow_datasets/iris/2.0.0. *Subsequent calls will reuse this data.* "- really covinient... but if you'd better take dataset from url (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#simple_batching) - pipelines are convinient):

```
# https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_csv_data
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

# test_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file("temperature.csv", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/daily-min-temperatures.csv")

titanic_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file("train.csv", "https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(titanic_file)
df.head()
# make dataset from pandas:
myDataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(df))

for feature_batch in myDataset.take(1):
  for key, value in feature_batch.items():
    print("  {!r:20s}: {}".format(key, value))

titanic_lines = tf.data.TextLineDataset(titanic_file)
for line in titanic_lines.take(10):
   print(line.numpy())
```

[here](https://www.openml.org/search?type=data&sort=runs&status=active) are different Datasets & Flows also